# How to call an method in grand child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have nested components. I want to call a method in grandchild component when i press on toggle in grand parent component.

Grand Parent Component

```
<div class="col text-right">
            Show Values:
            <ejs-switch
              class="form-control form-control-sm"
              (change)="displayGrillsValue($event)"
              [checked]=true
            ></ejs-switch>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="ContentControl">
                <app-grills-kpi [isInEdit]="isInEdit" [maxWidth]="'450px'" [maxHeight]="'30px'" [controlName]="ControlName.GrillsKPI1"></app-grills-kpi>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="ContentControl">
                <app-grills-kpi [isInEdit]="isInEdit" [maxWidth]="'450px'" [maxHeight]="'30px'" [controlName]="ControlName.GrillsKPI2"></app-grills-kpi>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Parent Component :

```
<app-grills-kpi-chart #chart [grillsKPIModel]="grillsKPIModel" [exportName]="formattedKPIName">
        </app-grills-kpi-chart>
```

Grand child component :

This is the method that i want to call

```
displayGrillsValue = ($event) => {
    this.chart.visibleSeries.forEach(element => {
      if($event.checked){
        element.marker = this.marker;
      }else {
      element.marker.dataLabel.visible =  $event.checked;
      }
    });
    this.chart.refresh();
  }
```

Please guide me the best way to do it. Also if you have noticed that i have 2 charts in the grand parent. So when i press the toggle button i want both the chart to be refreshed by grand child method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use BehaviorSubject or Subject to trigger the function call

TriggerService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TriggerService{
  constructor(){}
  private _trigger = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  castTrigger = this._trigger.asObservable();
  
  trigger(){
    this._trigger.next(''); 
  }
}
```

parent.component.ts

```
  constructor(private triggerService: TriggerService){}

  displayGrillsValue(){
      this.triggerService.trigger();
  }
```

child.component.ts

```
constructor(private triggerService: TriggerService){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.triggerService.castTrigger.subscribe(data => // grand child component logic here);
}
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example-l2b3dw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fuser.service.ts)

Comment: but in this how do i call the grand child component and refresh both the charts? Do i need to call the service in grand child component directly?

Comment: no you can trigger child component method from parent because child is subscribed to that subject.. please see stackblitz demo

Comment: i think in your example it is only parent child but in my i have grand parent as well so in that case how to do

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can have n number of child components as long as child components are  subscribed to that subject

Comment: got it so you mean that in my grand child component i can subscribe to that subject am i right?